# iOS streaming user camera on html5 without WebRTC

Tags: javascript, iphone

Does there have any way to help me streaming devices's camera on web page?
I need to keep show it on html5's video tag can't use like `<input type="file" capture="camera">`this code or Native Code.
thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, like you states, `WebRTC` is not supported on iOS devices (keep yourself updated [using this page](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/)). **streaming** a video from a web page on an iOS device is not possible using conventioal HTML or Javascript methods. You can upload a video element, but not stream it. That would require access to `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` or `navigator.GetUserMedia`, which again, is not supported on iOS browsers (yet).